# how to arrange the data when you melt

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(Data = c("P718_Rep1", "P718_Rep2", "P718_Rep3", 
"Trans17_Rep1", "Trans17_Rep2", "Trans17_Rep3", "Ham8Y_Rep1", 
"Ham8Y_Rep2", "Ham8Y_Rep3"), Condition1 = c(30100000, 37700000, 
4.27e+10, 1.11e+10, 1.3e+10, 0, 2.05e+09, 3.52e+09, 1.75e+10), 
H1 = c(4.49e+08, 4.31e+08, 3.89e+10, 1.28e+11, 1.5e+11, 0, 
5.5e+10, 6.38e+10, 1.89e+10), H2 = c(4.07e+08, 1.98e+08, 
1.75e+10, 1.24e+11, 8.21e+10, 0, 4.41e+10, 3.14e+10, 1.46e+09
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I try to melt it like this

```
mydf <- df %>% gather(Var, Value, -Data) %>%
  arrange(Data) %>% group_by(Data)
```

I plot it like this which is not correct

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = Var, y = Value))+
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c("Condition1","H1","H2" ))
```

I want to be able to make 3 plots

One is Ham8Y with all reps
One for P718 with all reps
One for Trans17 with all reps

```
Data       Var              Value
Ham8Y_Rep1  Condition1     2.05E+09
Ham8Y_Rep2  Condition1     3.52E+09
Ham8Y_Rep3  Condition1     1.75E+10
Ham8Y_Rep1  H1             5.50E+10
Ham8Y_Rep2  H1             6.38E+10
Ham8Y_Rep3  H1             1.89E+10
Ham8Y_Rep1  H2             4.41E+10
Ham8Y_Rep2  H2             3.14E+10
Ham8Y_Rep3  H2             1.46E+09
P718_Rep1 Condition1       30100000
P718_Rep2 Condition1       37700000
P718_Rep3 Condition1       4.27E+10
P718_Rep1 H1               4.49E+08
P718_Rep2 H1               4.31E+08
P718_Rep3 H1               3.89E+10
P718_Rep1 H2               4.07E+08
P718_Rep2 H2               1.98E+08
P718_Rep3 H2               1.75E+10
Trans17_Rep1  Condition1  1.11E+10
Trans17_Rep2  Condition1  1.30E+10
Trans17_Rep3  Condition1  0
Trans17_Rep1  H1          1.28E+11
Trans17_Rep2  H1          1.50E+11
Trans17_Rep3  H1          0
Trans17_Rep1  H2          1.24E+11
Trans17_Rep2  H2          8.21E+10
Trans17_Rep3  H2          0
```

It can be three plots and the median of the 3 replicate with their standard deviation

Comment: In your `mydf`, you have "Condition1", "H1" and "H2" in the `Var` column, but in your `ggplot`, you are setting limits with "Condition12" and "Condition3", which are not present in the input of `ggplot`. Try removing `scale_x_discrete(limit = c("Condition1", "Condition12", "Condition3"))` from your `ggplot` code and see if it's what you want

Comment: @benson23 I corrected it, thanks , I think it is now clear ? It gives a better solution but I still cannot get the Median and SD for each of them and make 3 plots

Comment: Can you expand when you say 3 plots?

Comment: `library(stringr)
;
mydf[c('experiment','replication')]=stringr::str_split_fixed(mydf$Data, '_', 2)
;
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = Var, y = Value,  group =experiment, colour = experiment))+
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point() `